# Amazon Product Advertising API C#

Tags: c#, amazon-product-api

Can somebody tell me C# excample of using Amazon Product Advertising API, for example to lookup item. All i found is not working now because of changes.

The most popular error is "Failed serialization of message body: ItemSearchRequest1 cant create temporary class"

Comment: Since they have the WSDL support, I would think you'd just have to add a reference to the web service in VS and be good to go, at least in terms of getting the call to go out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a C# sample here:

http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/3941

FWIW, [the AWS thread I mentioned](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=72429) includes these steps for a workaround:

> These are the steps as of January 31, 2012 to fix this issue in Visual
>   Studio for .Net clients:
>
> 1) Click the "Show all files" button in the Solution Explorer for the
>   project containing the amazon service reference.
>
> 2) Expand the
>   reference and open the AWSECommerceService.wsdl file in the editor
>
> 3)
>   On line 584 change the "maxOccurs' to "1".

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ImageSets">
```

> 4) Save the AWSECommerceService.wsdl file
>
> 5) Right click
>   Reference.svcmap and click "Run custom tool"
>
> 6) Expand
>   Reference.svcmap and open either Reference.cs or Reference.vb

Comment: i tried this but it isnt working i guess it because of new changes

Comment: FWIW, a quick google search seems to show a related thread @ https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=72429

Comment: Good to know!  If you don't mind, add an entry on that AWS thread mentioning that it's still needed as of May 2012. :)

Comment: Lol, just encountered the exact same bug! July 26th of 2011 first occurrence, now over a year later, still there!

Comment: By the way, it seems that my reference.cs is not updated and I still have 400 bad requests

Comment: link to download the sample is unfortunately broken :(

Comment: This steps works like a charm. But did not understand what is the deal for step 5 and 6?

Comment: @niico probably easiest to just use the nuget package from the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36149251/215534 but optionally there’s the api details at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising/) package.

```
PM> Install-Package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising
```

**Search example**

```
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication();
authentication.AccessKey = "accesskey";
authentication.SecretKey = "secretkey";

var client = new AmazonProductAdvertisingClient(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.DE);
var result = await client.SearchItemsAsync("canon eos");
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope it will not use your associate id and access key :)

Comment: The code is open source you can build your own binary https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising

Comment: Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising -Not able to build. its keep throwing some errors on xml attributes(assembly reference missing eventhough Sytesm.Xml referenced), Any Idea ?

Comment: I think here is the wrong place, if you have a problem create a issue

Comment: I meant the source code you referred github.com/tinohager/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising.  Can you able to build the source code in gitgub ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Html REST instead of Soap/Wsdl, I put an example updated for the 2011 API and Visual Studio 2012 on my blog: ["Up to date CSharp REST sample"](http://www.bgsoftfactory.net/index.php/how-to-send-an-authenticated-rest-request-to-the-amazon-product-advertising-api-using-c/)

Comment: The link you provided appears to be broken.

Comment: You're right, and I am sorry! The site is now bilingual, english/french, so the URL for his post changed. I edited the URL in the comment above, let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: I just realised the link was broken again, I just updated it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You saved my day. Been searching for a while and could not find a working solution. Your solution is very simple and love the light weight REST method.

Comment: @bernardG I could not find a link to the source code. Did you remove it?

Comment: Link still dead.